# How can I get the following query into a JSON object?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have two tables: `users` with fields `user_id` and `name`, and `transactions` with fields `transaction_id`, `user_id`, `amount` and two other irrelevant fields.

Now I have the following query, which lists per user_id the name and the sum of the amounts.

```
select users.*, SUM(transactions.anount) 
from users,transactions 
where users.user_id = transaction.user_id 
group by users.user_id
```

Now I want this to be in JSON format. So something like:

```json
[{user_id: 1, name: foo, amount: 13},{user_id: 2, name: bar, amount:-5}]
```

How can I do this? I am assuming with `json_object_agg` and `json_agg`, but I cannot get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your base query as a derived table, then aggregate that result into a JSON:

```
select json_agg(to_jsonb(t))
from (
  select u.user_id, u.name, sum(t.amount) as amount
  from users u
     join transactions t on t.user_id = u.user_id
  group by u.user_id
) t
```